# looking for a responsive javascript charting library

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

There are a couple of good charting libs out there, but most of them are not responsive.

I have tried morris.js but this isn't responsive.

So I am looking for one who is responsive and free and looks good like morris.js(**no highcharts, flot, google**)

Anybody?

Comment: Most of the charting libraries are "responsive" with a bit of work. [d3](http://d3js.org/) is probably one of the best out there; [here's a thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/d3-js/ggJSfR_uVMY) on how to make it "responsive."

Comment: It's not what can be called responsive, but morris.js charts have a resize attribute that if you set to true "enable automatic resizing when the containing element resizes"

Comment: For more 3D advanced stuff try three.js: http://threejs.org/examples/

Answer (score 9):

Try amCharts:

http://www.amcharts.com/javascript-charts/

They respond to container changes dynamically so would be perfect for adaptive layouts.

Comment: Just FYI, amCharts now have full-fledged responsive support. Take a look at this page for more info: http://www.amcharts.com/blog/responsive-charts/

Comment: It is. You can download fully functional libraries and use completely free of charge. Including commercial applications. No strings attached.

Comment: I use some other completely free js library in the end, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 5):

you can use chartjs

https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js

and my extended solution to make it responsive

https://github.com/arifLogic/respChartJS

---

EDIT :

now we can use responsive chart like Chartist js. Yet, there is many more js library out there. https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/

Answer (score 1):

You could use JS charts, this is all client side and is responsive
http://www.jscharts.com

Comment: From the JS Charts website: *"The free JS Charts version is fully customizable but watermarked."*

Comment: Seen it, but it's missing an area charts and the charts look poor. Thanks any way :-)

Comment: switch it: ChartJS: http://www.chartjs.org/. Much better.